# How to validate which data (rows) to load to a DB from a table in excel?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ssis, webforms

I have an excel table of 3 columns and 5 rows, which I want to upload to the DB as long as they meet the requirements (I mean the rows)

For example: If of 5 rows, in the third row of the column "cost" you put the word "hundred"(in spanish "cien") or any other, only charge to the DB the row 1, 2, 4 and 5.

```
ID Name  cost
1  Juan  100
2  Pablo 200
3  Jose  cien
4  Maria 400
5  Pedro 500
```

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC0ix.png)

I'm using C# on asp.net web and sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [global errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/review-data-type-mapping-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15#specify-global-error-handling-options) on the sql server side as it's best practice. Using the wizard you can set the "on error" column to "Ignore the error" and keep loading the data.